# A good Stanford POStagger example for python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

```
http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/
```

I want to use tagger one in my python code but in this link:

```
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml
```

Python link doesn't work anymore i think is there a good tutorial or example code how to use this tagger function for text ? Also some of stanford taggers can't be imported with nltk.download(). Which version should i use. A link or an example would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a for linux and https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9 for windows

Comment: thank you for reply all the tutorials is helped me a lot. But if its not interrupt your workcan you take a look at my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744146/nltk-chunk-only-nnp-tags-and-rewrite-the-sentence

Comment: I see you are very experienced with nlp. Any help would be very beneficial for my current project thanks again