# NLTK - Chunk only NNP tags and rewrite the sentence

Tags: java, python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

With this:

```
from nltk.chunk.util import tagstr2tree
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
text = "John Rose Center is very beautiful place and i want to go there with Barbara Palvin. Also there are stores like Adidas ,Nike ,Reebok Center."
tagged_text = pos_tag(text.split())
tagged_text_string = " ".join(["{}/{}".format(word,pos) for word, pos in tagged_text])
print(tagstr2tree(tagged_text_string))
```

I get this:

```
(S
  John/NNP
  Rose/NNP
  Center/NNP
  is/VBZ
  very/RB
  beautiful/JJ
  place/NN
  and/CC
  i/NN
  want/VBP
  to/TO
  go/VB
  there/RB
  with/IN
  Barbara/NNP
  Palvin./NNP
  Also/RB
  there/EX
  are/VBP
  stores/NNS
  like/IN
  Adidas/NNP
  ,Nike/NNP
  ,Reebok/NNP
  Center./NNP)
```

I want to parse only NNP tags but i can't figure out what to write in grammer part.I want my output like this:

```
(S
  John/NNP Rose/NNP Center/NNP
  is/VBZ
  very/RB
  beautiful/JJ
  place/NN
  and/CC
  i/NN
  want/VBP
  to/TO
  go/VB
  there/RB
  with/IN
  Barbara/NNP Palvin./NNP
  Also/RB
  there/EX
  are/VBP
  stores/NNS
  like/IN
  Adidas/NNP
  ,Nike/NNP
  ,Reebok/NNP Center./NNP)
```

There is example in tutorial http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html how should i define parser but i want to only parse NNP tags as i said.Also after that is it possible to rewrite the tokenized sentence like John Rose Center , Barbara Palvin or Reebok Center as one dict member(Remove tags and rewrite the sentence):

```
[John Rose Center] is very beautiful place and i want to go there with [Barbara Palvin]. Also there are stores like [Adidas] ,[Nike] ,[Reebok Center].
```

I will be very very thankful if somebody help me out these tools are very hard to play who began to code with python.

**EDIT:**

```
from nltk.chunk.util import tagstr2tree
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
text = "John Rose Center is very beautiful place and i want to go there with Barbara Palvin. Also there are stores like Adidas ,Nike ,Reebok Center."
tagged_text = pos_tag(text.split())

grammar = "NP:{<NNP>+}"

cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(tagged_text)

print(result)
```

The code i wrote can chunk NNP tags only but i can't read commas. Therefore it always counts Adidas,Nike,Reebok as one line.The solutions is write something in grammer and read commas then parse.

```
(S
  (NP John/NNP Rose/NNP Center/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  very/RB
  beautiful/JJ
  place/NN
  and/CC
  i/NN
  want/VBP
  to/TO
  go/VB
  there/RB
  with/IN
  (NP Barbara/NNP Palvin./NNP)
  Also/RB
  there/EX
  are/VBP
  stores/NNS
  like/IN
  (NP Adidas/NNP ,Nike/NNP ,Reebok/NNP Center./NNP))
```

Comment: You should use NER tagger instead of POS tagger.

Comment: The problem that my current graduating project is Named Entity Recognizer for Turkish.First i can take at least 3 words(not more) and find thier types(person,location,organization).But things changed i have to find proper nouns more than 4 or 5 words. So i should only find proper names as in my question.sorry for long comment